# MyFatoorah Payment getaway for the Kuwait App

Tags: ios, swift, payment

I am Developing Shopping App and i am using https://myfatoorah.com/ for the Online payment Here are some of my Issue related to this Payment getaway
(Payment Currency is KWD)

1) i am Adding product with decimal point price not working ie 1.345 KWD (it will convert integer value while i switch to payment getaway screen. ie

2) after going to payment getaway screen with 1st item with QTY 1 and and second item with QTY 1  and then after i cancel the payment screen and come back to my app and change the QTY with 2 and again go to the payment screen its not displaying updated QTY value

inout data

```
 {
        name = Regular;
        price = "0.145";
        "product_id" = 1;
        qty = 2;
    },
        {
        name = "Sugar Free";
        price = "0.145";
        "product_id" = 2;
        qty = 4;
    },
        {
        name = "Corn Oil";
        price = "2.495";
        "product_id" = 9;
        qty = 1;
    }
```

output in myFatoorah SDK screen

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Fatoorah Fix This Problem and Update New SDK In Github. https://github.com/MyFatoorahHub/MFSDK